# CMAKE: Unique variable names ignored

Tags: linux, cmake, cross-platform, embedded-linux

I've a cross platform project running on multiple platforms. There is a CmakeLists.txt in every directory in the project and most cmake files have code similar to:

**Input:**

```
# set target os
if (DEFINED target_os)
 SET (HRAD_SDK_TARGET_OS "${target_os}")
else ()
 SET (HRAD_SDK_TARGET_OS "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")
endif ()
message(STATUS "=============== SDK: ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc==============")
message(STATUS "target_os: ${target_os}")
message(STATUS "HRAD_SDK_TARGET_OS: ${HRAD_SDK_TARGET_OS}")

# set target bit
if ("${HRAD_SDK_TARGET_OS}" MATCHES "Linux")
 message(STATUS "=============== SDK: ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd==============")
 message(STATUS "target_os: ${target_os}")
 message(STATUS "HRAD_SDK_TARGET_OS: ${HRAD_SDK_TARGET_OS}")

 if ("${target_arch_bit}" MATCHES "64")
  SET (TARGET_ARCH_BIT -m64)
 else ()
  SET (TARGET_ARCH_BIT -m32)
 endif ()
endif ()
message(STATUS "TARGET_ARCH_BIT: ${TARGET_ARCH_BIT}")
# set flags
SET (ADDITION_C_FLAGS "-Wno-unused -Wno-parentheses")
if ("${HRAD_SDK_TARGET_OS}" MATCHES "LinuxARM")
 message(STATUS "=============== SDK: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==============")
 message(STATUS "target_os: ${target_os}")
 message(STATUS "HRAD_SDK_TARGET_OS: ${HRAD_SDK_TARGET_OS}")
```

In the above sample, `target_os` can have values such as `Linux, LinuxARM, MacOSX, QNX` etc.

However, for some reason it doesn't like the name `LinuxARM`, it seems to treat it as `Linux`.

In the code above even if `target_os` is `LinuxARM`, somehow the loop with `Linux` check is true and I get output as below and compilation fails -

**Output:**

```
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- =============== SDK: ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc==============
-- target_os: LinuxARM
-- HRAD_SDK_TARGET_OS: LinuxARM
-- =============== SDK: ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd==============
-- target_os: LinuxARM
-- HRAD_SDK_TARGET_OS: LinuxARM
-- TARGET_ARCH_BIT: -m32
-- =============== SDK: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==============
-- target_os: LinuxARM
-- HRAD_SDK_TARGET_OS: LinuxARM
-- =============== utils: CMakeLists.txt ==============
-- target os: LinuxARM
-- TARGET_OS: 
-- CMAKE_C_FLAGS:  -fPIC -Wno-unused -Wno-parentheses -D_REENTRANT
-- CMAKE_CPP_FLAGS:  -fPIC -Wno-unused -Wno-parentheses -std=gnu++0x -D_REENTRANT
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:   -fPIC -Wno-unused -Wno-parentheses -std=gnu++0x -D_REENTRANT
-- CMAKE_LD_FLAGS: -Wl -rpath-link,/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib
-- CMAKE_C_COMPILER: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
-- CMAKE_CPP_COMPILER: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
```

As you can see it shouldn't have gone in the block containing the line
`ddddddddddddddddddddddddd`

If I rename `LinuxARM` to so some other name such as `LINUX_ARM` or totally random such as `NEWHLOS` then the code compiles fine.

Seems like since `Linux` is a subset of `LinuxARM`, it just treats it as `Linux`.

Can someone help why it doesn't like `LinuxARM`? I read that cmake variable names are case sensitive, but in my cases the variables are completely unique.

Also, I deleted all the cmake cache files and deleted all previous build files but issue persists.

**Update 1:**

`LINUX_ARM` seems to have no issue with `Linux`. It works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MATCHES` subcommand of `if()` does a *regular expression match,* as [documented](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html). Of course the text `LinuxARM` matches the regex `Linux`. What you want is `STREQUAL`, not `MATCHES`:

```
if ("${HRAD_SDK_TARGET_OS}" STREQUAL "Linux")
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that MATCHES does a regex match.

Comment: @kaushal Reading the docs would have saved you the hassle of having to write an SO question and wait for an asnwer ;-)

Comment: yes, it would have. This is the first time I'm using Cmake, so still learning things. :)